# Wordpress Category displays unwanted products

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a tree of categories

Main - Brand - Types

When I click on one of the main categories it is displaying "BRAND" category along with all of the products listed as well...

How can I get rid of this list, where I only want my subcategories and get the list of products only to be displayed in the correct subcategory?

In the Categories display options I have "subcategories" clicked, tried all options - did not change anything. 
In the Product display options I have tried all options too - it is on "search" for now.

Any ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see where the problem is?

Comment: happily, but not sure which file it would be - i did not change anything in the code, apart from the css and the design side - it was like this from the start, so not sure what code I could show in here....